# Itextsharp pdf generated with Norwegian adds bottom padding after some text

Tags: c#, itext, multilingual

[image: English language in PDF]

[image: Norwegian language in PDF]

pdf generated with Norwegian using Itextsharp adds bottom padding after some text.
Cannot reduce the padding as there is none. Cannot have fixed height as the quantity of text varies. cannot get the height of the row/cell as it can only be achieved once rendered

Edit: it only happens on top of a drop down list not with any other answer options.

Please, help.

```
    private static void AddTextCell(PdfPTable table, string text, int rowspan = 1, int colspan = 1, float border = 0f, float padding = 0f)
    {
        Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, BaseColor.BLACK);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, arial))
        {
            Rowspan = rowspan,
            Colspan = colspan,
            BorderWidth = 0f,
            PaddingTop = padding,
            PaddingBottom = padding,
            HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT,
            VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE
        };

        if (colspan > 1)
        {
             cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.CYAN;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GREEN;
        }

        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code you used to create this pdf.

Comment: There you go Amedee http://pastebin.com/URyCUyEz

Comment: Please put the *relevant* part of your code *inside* your question, not in a pastebin link that may go dead in a few days. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Don't mislead people by insinuating that the problem is caused by using Norwegian instead of English. Don't expect people to read all of your code. Nobody has time for that. **Trim the content you receive from the database or whatever source holds the data.** There's a high chance that there are plenty of white space characters in the Norwegian text. If that's the case, the fact that the language is Norwegian is irrelevant.

Comment: I was just asking for help! And definitely had no intentions to mislead anyone. I was editing the code to make it relevant! I have not asked many questions here. For your information, there are no trailing spaces in the text I just checked.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i did not know you are the original developer of iText. Apologies, for the title. As a creator anyone would get a bit furious. Can you please help?

Comment: @Harry Please simply ask yourself, would you know how to reproduce the issue if you got the information from your question? I don't. The code you added actually even made things more difficult as you show that colspan and rowspan might be involved as culprits here. As Amadee hinted at, please supply something short but runnable to reproduce the issue, i.e. a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). That been said, Bruno mentioned *white space characters*, not merely *space characters*. that can make quite a difference.

Comment: @mkl Ok will have a look and get back. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for pointing out. It was a problem with whitespace characters and not space characters. Bruno Lowagie was right. Thanks a lot guys. I will keep the requirements in mind the next time I post a question on stackoverflow. Apologies, for inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was whitespace characters in the source norwegian text.

I removed them using [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

> string textWithoutWhiteSpaceCharacters =    Regex.Replace(textWithWhiteSpaceCharacters, "[\n\r\t]", " ");